# How do you deserialize XML data to a List that was serialized from a List?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I've serialized a bunch of records from a list to an XML file with the following code. This works very well, and I have a really nice XML file that stores my data when I close my program.

How do I now read that data back into my list when the program opens? I can't seem to figure out how to cycle through the records in the file and store them in my list of records.

```
    private void WriteXML()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer XMLwriter = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(callsignRecord));

            System.IO.StreamWriter XMLfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Known Callsigns.xml");
            foreach (callsignRecord callsign in Callsigns)
            {
                XMLwriter.Serialize(XMLfile, callsign);
            }
            XMLfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Below is as far as I got:

```
    private void ReadXML()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer XMLreader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(callsignRecord));

            System.IO.StreamReader XMLfile = new System.IO.StreamReader("Known Callsigns.xml");
            while(!XMLfile.EndOfStream)
            {
                // Okay, great I can Deseralize the file, but how do the records go from the file to the List with this?
                XMLreader.Deserialize(XMLfile);
            }
            XMLfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

For reference, the data stored in the XML file came from a list with the following format:

```
public class callsignRecord
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public List<AliasRecord> AliasRecords;
}

public class AliasRecord
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried serializing the whole list as an object instead of doing it record by record, but that didn't work to well either.

EDIT: The code shown below does work. The reason it failed when I tried it was I started by trying to deserialize a list that was serialized record by record. Clearly the two approaches aren't compatible the code below is the correct approach to this.

```
    private void WriteXML()
    {
        try
        {
            var XMLwriter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<callsignRecord>));

            System.IO.StreamWriter XMLfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Known Callsigns.xml");
            XMLwriter.Serialize(XMLfile, Callsigns);
            XMLfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReadXML()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader XMLfile;
        try
        {
            var XMLreader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<callsignRecord>));

            XMLfile = new System.IO.StreamReader("Known Callsigns.xml");
            Callsigns = (List<callsignRecord>)XMLreader.Deserialize(XMLfile);
            XMLfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            //XMLfile.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your last code-block that serializes the whole list as an object worked fine for me, and should work for you too. Can you be more specific about what didn't work well when testing this particular code block?

Comment: @har07 Strange. When attempting to read, it comes back with "There is an error in XML document(2,2). When atempting to write, I get an error telling me the file is being used by another process. I don't understand that, since I only do file access on program start and program close.

Comment: @har07 So after, reading your post, I went back to my program. The file I was trying to open at the start of the program had originally be serialized record by record, so it couldn't be deserialized. The code worked when I made sure the file was serialized as an object before trying to deserialize it as an object. I guess I need to add code at the start to check for an existing file before trying to open it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
     // Create an instance of CallsignRecordclass.
     CallsignRecord serializeObject = new CallsignRecord();
     // Create an instance of new TextReader.
     TextReadertxtReader = new StreamReader(@”C:\Callsigns.xml”);
     // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
     XmlSerializerxmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CallsignRecord));
     // Deserialize from the StreamReader.
     serializeObject = (CallsignRecord)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);
     // Close the stream reader
     txtReader.Close();
```

check here for details

[XML Serialization and Deserialization: Part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

[XML Serialization and Deserialization: Part-2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)